# How can I implement my own File type?

Tags: go

I am having a function that opens a file and writes to it using the `os.OpenFile` function.

What I basically want to do is mock the File that is getting returned by it in order to write tests. Because I want to better understand Go, I'd like to do it without using third party packages.

Here is what I have tried:

**My Package**

```
package logger

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "sync"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "path/filepath"
    "io"
)

const timestampFormat = "2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999"

type FileOpener interface {
    OpenFile(name string, flag int, perm os.FileMode) (*os.File, error)
}

type RotateWriter struct {
    fileOpener FileOpener
    lock       sync.Mutex
    filename   string
    fp         *os.File
}

type defaultFileOpener struct{}

func (fo defaultFileOpener) OpenFile(name string, flag int, perm os.FileMode) (*os.File, error) {
    return os.OpenFile(name, flag, perm)
}

func CreateRotateWriter(filename string, fileOpener FileOpener) (RotateWriter) {
    if (fileOpener == nil) {
        return RotateWriter{filename: filename, fileOpener: defaultFileOpener{}}
    }
    return RotateWriter{filename: filename, fileOpener: fileOpener}
}

func (writer RotateWriter) Write(bytes []byte) (int, error) {
    writer.lock.Lock()
    defer writer.lock.Unlock()

    extension := filepath.Ext(writer.filename)
    filename := strings.TrimSuffix(writer.filename, extension)

    // There is a specific constants that are used for formatting dates.
    // For example 2006 is the YYYYY, 01 is MM and 02 is DD
    // Check https://golang.org/src/time/format.go line 88 for reference
    fullFilename := filename + time.Now().UTC().Format("-2006-01-02") + extension

    // Open the file for the first time if we don't already did so
    if writer.fp == nil {
        fp, err := os.OpenFile(fullFilename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
        if err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }
        writer.fp = fp;
    }

    // We are now pointing to a different file. Close the previous one and open a new one
    if fullFilename != writer.fp.Name() {
        writer.fp.Close()
        fp, err := os.OpenFile(fullFilename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
        if err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }
        writer.fp = fp;
    }

    return writer.fp.Write([]byte("[" + time.Now().UTC().Format(timestampFormat) + "] " + string(bytes)))
}
```

What I was hoping to do in my test package is something like this

```
type file interface {
    io.Closer
    io.Reader
    io.ReaderAt
    io.Seeker
    Stat() (os.FileInfo, error)
}

type fileType struct{
    fd      int
    name    string
    contents string // Where I'll keep the in-memory contents maybe
}
type defaultFileOpener struct{

}
func (fo defaultFileOpener) OpenFile(name string, flag int, perm os.FileMode) (*file, error){
    return &fileType{1, name, ""}, nil //Cannot use &fileType{1, name, ""}(type *fileType) as type *file
}

func (f fileType) Write(bytes []byte) (int, error){
    f.contents += string(bytes)
    return len(bytes), nil
}
```

I'm most probably misunderstand something, is it even possible to create my own File type in go?

Comment: `fileType` needs to implement **all** of `file`'s methods. And you should not return a pointer to an interface. Your functions should have a return type of `file` not `*file`.

Comment: The return signature of `os.OpenFile` is `(*file, error)`, doesn't that mean I must return a pointer?

Comment: ... see here https://play.golang.org/p/J-VQoHWLEcU you can see that it compiles, and if you comment out just one method you'll get an error.

Comment: yes it means that if that's your signature, but it is recommended not to return pointers to interfaces, it makes little to no sense. And `*fileType` is not gonna pass as `*file`, while if you implement the methods it is gonna pass as `file`. A pointer to an interface is not the same as the interface itself, and therefore a you cannot use a value that implements an interface as the pointer to that interface.

Comment: They are just two different types and so your program won't compile. If you're not clear on how interfaces work try taking the [Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9).

Comment: I will do that, your comments were very helpful and my test works now :)

If you make an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the snippet it's not clear whether or not the `*fileType` implements all of the methods of the `file` interface, but if it doesn't you should first make sure that it does. Because if it doesn't you'll not be able to use it in your tests as you might intend.

---

Your file opener's `OpenFile` method should have the interface as its return type, not the pointer to the interface. That is:

```
func (fo defaultFileOpener) OpenFile(name string, flag int, perm os.FileMode) (file, error) {
```

This is because *`*file` is not the same type as `file`*, and a value of a type that implements the `file` interface (e.g. yours `*fileType`) cannot be used where the pointer to that interface is expected.

---

And returning a pointer to an interface is almost never what you actually want, *maybe* it would make sense to do that if you wanted switch the interface value for another using pointer indirection, but that does not seem to be the case here. If you scan through the standard library you'll have a hard time finding functions/methods that return pointers to interface types...

But let's say that that's what you want to do then you have to return a pointer to a value of the interface type, not a pointer to a type that implements the interface.

E.g.

```
var f file = &fileType{} // f is of type file
return &f, nil           // &f is of type *file
```

Keep in mind that `f`'s type has to be `file` for the return to work, if it's just `*fileType` it will not compile.

```
var f = &fileType{} // f is of type *fileType
return &f, nil      // &f is of type **fileType
```